# Compiling a C program and linking

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, sdl

Do I understand it correctly on how to use cmake for linking

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Sdltest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Sdltest ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I'm trying to link the sdl2 to my project but I get a lot of errors.

like ***/src/mingw-org-wsl/4.0-dev/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'***

When I use gcc on cmd, it compiles perfectly

```
gcc main.c -o test -Wall -Werror -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

By the way I use clion 1.0.5

Comment: And now please write 100 times: "C is **not** C++ is **not** C!"

Comment: @Olaf `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) C != C++ != C;` compilation error, please halp (yes, no typo here). :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the flags, you mix *compiler* and *linker* flags. First of all this is problematic because the compiler flags aren't used when linking, and secondly because the GNU linker needs the libraries to come after the main source (or object) file on the command line, just like when you build manually.

You set the libraries by using the [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_link_libraries.html) command in your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
target_link_libraries(Sdltest mingw32 SDL2main SDL2)
```

Also, you're not building a C++ project, you're building a C project, so the flags variable should be `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.

Finally, if you're wondering about the command and arguments that CMake uses when building, try making with `VERBOSE` set to non-zero, e.g.

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

I'm sure it's possible to add that argument to CLion.

---

PS.

If you want to enable more warnings, there are even more flags you could add, like `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`. Yes it might sometime give false positives, especially when including header files from external libraries, but I think it's better to have to many warnings when developing than to few.

Comment: by the way do you have an Idea why it would output fatal error Out of memory

Comment: nevermind I added this before including sdl `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and everything works, don't know why it works with gcc without that code,maybe i'll be using gcc for the meantime